# OSGI Blueprint jaxrs server endpoint configuration - how to configure address?

Tags: java, osgi, jax-rs, blueprint-osgi

I have a REST service I've set up using OSGI (running in Karaf).

```
<jaxrs:server address="http://localhost:9001/rest" id="myFileService" >
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref component-id="FileServicesImpl" />
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
</jaxrs:server>
```

When I browse to `http://localhost:8181/cxf`, if lists my services, and I can successfully connect to my service at `http://localhost:9001/rest` .  If I go to `http://MyMachineName:8181/cxf`, I get the service list, but if I go to `http://MyMachineName:9001/rest` the address is not found.

For what it's worth, when I browse to the /cxf link using MyMachineName, it still lists the endpoint as localhost.

Is there a way to configure the endpoint address in the blueprint config so that it responds the both localhost and the machine name? Or to just specific the port? Or do I have to hardcode the machine name or incorporate it into a config file and force it to the machine name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options here. The first is using `http://0.0.0.0:9001/rest` as url. This will tell cxf to bind to all ip adresses the server has.

The other option which I prefer is to just user `/rest` as url. In this case cxf will bind to the OSGi http service which is implemented by pax web in karaf. So you can setup the port and eventually https settings on the pax web level.

Comment: Thanks!  I wondered about just `/rest` from some of the examples I saw, but ended up going with `http://0.0.0.0`.  That seems to work fine, at this point it's mostly an annoyance that the default services list at `:8181/cxf` explicitly lists the 0.0.0.0 address instead of inferring it, but that's on me :-)